# What is the used measure in $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I have a question regarding the definition of measure zero.

On page 3 of this [document](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07276.pdf), point (i) states that

"The proof does not use Lebesgue measure theory (Fubini's Theorem or whatever else). we talk only about sets of measure zero; by definition, set $C$ has measure zero where $C \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$,

if for any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a system $\{B = B(y, \delta_y ) \}_{y \in Y}$ of balls in $\mathbb{R}^d$, such that

$$
\sum_{y \in Y} \delta_y^d < \epsilon, \text{ and } C \subseteq \cup_{y\in Y} B(y, \delta_y ).
$$ "

The above statements seem to indicate that the above definition of measure zero is not using the Lebesgue measure. Then

1. What measure is used in the above definition of measure zero? Is it Hausdorff measure?
2. Is this measure also limited to finite-dimensional spaces, like the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: Looks like it's the Lebesgue measure. The Lebesgue measure of a ball of radius $\delta$ in $\Bbb{R}^d$ is of the form $K\cdot \delta^d$, where $K=K_d$ is some slightly cumbersome constant that is inconvenient to evaluate (and depends on $d$). The exact value of the constant is totally uninteresting, because it can be absorbed into $\epsilon$ for the purposes of defining a null set. For example, $K_1=2$, $K_2=\pi$, $K_3=4\pi/3$ etc.

Comment: The point seems to be that the proof doesn't need the full concept of the Lebesgue measure for arbitrary measurable sets, it only needs the concept of “zero (Lebesgue) measure”.